export render pass without re-render 3d scene
I'm rendering an image and i've turned ON all the passes/layers that I needed. In the Image editor I can see my render result and all the passes correctly. But I don't like the naming used for those passes. So I create custom name by using 'file output' in the compositor. After re wiring all the passes data from render result into this file output , how can I execute that 'file output' without have to re render the 3d scene again which takes long time. This should be only transfering the data that already be rendered into another multi exr file with my new custom name which in my opinion should be done as 2d processing.


You can create a new View Layer and choose Blank as option, this way all collections will be disabled in that new layer, objects which are not in collections would have to be disabled for render manually. But now this way there is nothing in the scene which gets rendered, so it would render much quicker than your actual view layer.
If you then go to the View Layer Properties and enable Render Single Layer, hitting F12 to start a new render will only render this empty view layer.

The good thing is, it will keep the previously rendered other view layer in memory, which can for example be useful if you want to combine two view layers in the Compositor, make changes in only one of them and don't want to render both again. Then you check Render Single Layer on the changed layer and the Compositor will use the other layer from memory.
Now useful for you is, the Compositor will also save what is plugged into the File Output another time, even though you do not render that layer again. But important to note is, it can only output a render result which has been stored in memory previously. Which means, if you have passes now enabled which were not enabled when you rendered the scene earlier, those output sockets will provide no data. Only if they were already enabled while rendering. But if you have data there and only wanted to change them to custom names, these custom names will be assigned the next time it saves the file.
